# using the original type or a Type object in generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

If your given a Type Object like

```
var myType = typeof(SomeClass)
```

Is it possible to get the original type, being an interface or class and using it in generics.

for example

```
var myObject = container.Resolve<myType>()
```

so this would create an object of type SomeClass in this situation.

To clarify i'm trying to create a wrapper around an Ioc container so the Ioc framework can change without affecting any other code.

Comment: Yes, use reflection. Have a go and post the code that you write if you can't get it to work.

Comment: you need to get from IoC container?

Comment: for this particular problem kind of, its a wrapper class around an IoC container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `container.Resolve` means one of [`UnityContainer.Resolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainer.resolve.aspx) family, than there's [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650946.aspx), that accepts `Type` instance:

```
var obj = container.Resolve(typeObj);
```

It's a common feature for DI- or IoC-containers - to have coupled resolution overloads, for generic use-cases, and for non-generic ones.

Comment: It kind of is, i'm trying to make a wrapper class for an ioc container so the ioc implementation can change without affecting any other code. As a workaround i've done this but the current ioc is castle but they support that as well.

Comment: @RyanBurnham: If you want to write a wrapper, then you should decide, what resolution scenarios you will support. For generics, you must have something like 'T MyIoCWrapper.Resolve<T>', which will redirect calls to appropriate underlying container's `Resolve<T>` overload (generic too!). For non-generics, there will be `object MyIoCWrapper.Resolve(Type)`, which will call container's `Resolve(Type)`. I don't see here any need for reflection or expressions usage.

Comment: The problem i am facing is there is some tightly coupled code to the current IoC container where it takes an interface type an queries the container for any objects registered for that type. It might be best to just use Resolve(Type) method.

Comment: @RyanBurnham: is interface type known at compile-time?

Comment: @RyanBurnham: well, `object Resolve(Type)` is the best you can do here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear what you mean by "get the original type" - but if you want to use the type in generics, you'll usually need to use reflection. For example:

```
var methodDefinition = container.GetType().GetMethod("Resolve");
var constructedMethod = methodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(method);
object myObject = constructedMethod.Invoke(container, null);
```

The type of the `myObject` variable can only usefully be `object` - the type of a variable has to be known at compile-time (although it could be generic). If you're using C# 4 and .NET 4+ you could potentially use `dynamic` as an alternative - it depends on what you're trying to do with it afterwards.

If you find yourself having to make multiple reflection calls with the same type argument, consider extracting the logic into a new generic method - you can then use reflection *once* to call that method, and then just use normal generics within the method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need something like this:

```
T Resolve<T>()
{
    var myType = typeof(T);
    return (T)myType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });
}
```

And you use it:

```
YourClass l = Resolve<YourClass>();
```

This is an extremly simple example for a constructor with no params like

```
public YourClass(){...}
```

You could start reading from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h.aspx)

And you should always think it over very thoroughly whether you need reflection or not (consider the answer given by J.Skeet).

Comment: well, not too complicated ? `T Resolve<T>() where T : new() {return new T();}` . Which isn't that interesting, but does the same...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I said that it's only an example...he may need to use a constructor with params